# Truncating the last letter in the import list from the csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, import

This is my code:

```
import csv

with open('name.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  my_list = list(reader)

print(my_list)

def remove_cruft(s):
    return s[:-1]


new_list=[remove_cruft(s) for s in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[['robić'], ['marudzić'], ['biegać']]
[[], [], []]
```

Why does the method written by me not return a list with the last character of each individual element cut?

I would like to change from the import csv file in the form of a list, replace the last character of a particular element with several different variances with the tip and re-save them to a csv file.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reader` is an iterator that gives you list of all items in line at each iteration.
This is a useful solution, taking advantage of this iterator:

```
import csv

def remove_cruft(s):
    return s[:-1]

with open('name.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = [[remove_cruft(item) for item in line] for line in reader]

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[['robi'], ['marudzi'], ['biega']]
```

based on this content:

```
robić
marudzić
biegać
```

of `name.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're passing a list and not the actual string.

```
>>> s = [['robić'], ['marudzić'], ['biegać']]
>>> s[0]
['robić']

>>> s[0][:-1]
[]

>>> s[0][0]
'robić'

>>> s[0][0][:-1]
'robi'
```

This is due to the fact that your data is made of 2D lists. If you had structured your data like this:

```
>>> s = ['robić', 'marudzić', 'biegać']
>>> [remove_cruft(a) for a in s]
['robi', 'marudzi', 'biega']
```

It would work.

Answer (score 0):

this code solves the problem.

```
import csv

with open('name.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  my_list = list(reader)

print(my_list)

def remove_cruft(s):
    return s[:-1]


new_list=[remove_cruft(s) for s in my_list[0]]
print(new_list)
```

output :-

```
[['robić', 'marudzić', 'biegać']]
['robi', 'marudzi', 'biega']
```

Actually , the output your code produces is :-

```
[['robić', 'marudzić', 'biegać']]
[['robić', 'marudzić']]
```

you need pass strings to remove_cruft() , which can be done by traversing my_list[0]